# Android app that alerts other android devices nearby

Tags: android

So I am trying to develop an idea that has two core apps - 
The user
The "alerter"

Basically, the alerter sends out a message that is received by all the phones with the app made for the users, but within a specific radius and not all. Any old programs I can look up into? or any tips, ideas? I'm literally new to the android coding world.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways that could be done, including:

- Bluetooth detection

  - this is not feasible until Android supports becoming a Bluetooth Low Energy transmitter
- WiFi detection

  - the devices must be on same access point to have network connectivity with each other
- Server-side

  - All devices update a common server with their location
  - Devices can then query server for (reported) nearby devices
  - Server can also push new devices using GCM or [Push IO](http://push.io/)

You could maybe start by looking for apps that do this sort of thing already. One is the instant-messaging app [WeChat](http://www.wechat.com/en/), and there are also some dating apps that allow users to make contact with nearby potentials.

Also read [Find nearby users of an app (iPhone and Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7848093/823470)

Answer (score -2):

I think you should start with [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html):

> Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM) is a service that allows you
>   to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device,
>   and also to receive messages from devices on the same connection. The
>   GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery
>   to the target Android application running on the target device. GCM is
>   completely free no matter how big your messaging needs are, and there
>   are no quotas.